# How do I change bond colors to something besides a different hue in Coot?

Tags: structural-biology, coot

I can modify the colors of carbons in Coot under **Edit**, **Bond Colours...**, but that only gives me different hues.  Is there a way to change the color to something less-saturated (or perhaps slightly transparent) so I can identify the "active" molecule I'm working on versus a template?

The menus seem no help, I'm wondering if there's some scripting magic that can do this.

Comment: @Rory, they're not buttons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try other visual differences, like make what you're interested in ball-and-stick, and everything else wireframe, like in this example:

[image: like on this example].

.... Because, from: http://www.ysbl.york.ac.uk/~lohkamp/coot/doc/coot-python.html

> procedure: hilight_binding_site (imol, centre_residue_spec,
>   hilight_colour, radius): hilight-colour is specified in degrees (round
>   the colour wheel - starting at yellow (e.g. 230 is purple))

It looks from this like you only get to choose Hue (color_map_rotation) and not Saturation or Lightness, even with the script interface.

However, [text can be full RGB](http://biop.ox.ac.uk/coot/doc/coot-reference-manual.html)

> 3.28.3 (set-font-colour red green blue)
>
> where:
>
> red is an inexact number green is an inexact number blue is an inexact
>   number